# Specify module(s) to compile via pom file in a Maven multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, maven-module

Consider I have a Maven project with the following modules:

1. Multimodule (parent)
2. Webserver (simple web app)
3. Fullstack (simple web app that connects to a database)
4. Integration (runs rests against natively complied webserver and fullstack modules)

As I mentioned above, integration module is a module to test against natively complied webserver and fullstack modules. So it doesn't have a main class but it has a bunch of test classes that run http endpoints tests against the natively compiled modules.

From my [research](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html#:%7E:text=Making%20a%20Subset%20of%20Projects,(either%20directly%20or%20indirectly).), I know I can specify the modules to compile via Maven command `--projects`. Also from Maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html), if you scroll down to `Profiles` I can specify the modules to compile directly in the chosen profile. My root pom profile.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <modules>
                <module>webserver</module>
                <module>fullstack</module>
            </modules>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

I noticed every time I compile in `integration-test` profile using the command `mvn clean -Pintegration-test -DskipTests native:compile`, integration modules is also compiled.

My root POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>multimodule</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>webserver</module>
        <module>fullstack</module>
        <module>integration</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <module.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</module.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <modules>
                <module>webserver</module>
                <module>fullstack</module>
            </modules>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

When I run `mvn clean -Pintegration-test -DskipTests install` or `mvn clean -Pintegration-test -DskipTests native:compile`, all the modules are compiled:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] multimodule                                                        [pom]
[INFO] webserver                                                          [jar]
[INFO] fullstack                                                          [jar]
[INFO] integration                                                        [jar]
```